# What should be mentioned as "Front-end" of my simple iOS Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, frontend

For example, suppose I created a simple iOS project that get data from server using NSURLRequest and store using CoreData. Is Front-end should be marked as *Cocoa Touch* or *iOS* or *Objective-C* or *UIKit Framework* or *something else* ?

I am keen to find the term I should use while mentioning my iOS project.

Comment: Call it Fred if you want to. It sounds like you're filling out a form somewhere and it's asking you about a front end. Give us some background on your question. Where will this description be used?

Comment: Duncan C, Suppose I am demonstrating my iOS project and first slide would be what technology I have used, what's the platform on which it's going to be work, what's the Front-end and the Back-end of the project etc. I know all the answer except the specific answer for the Front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocoa Touch Framework would suffice, as it also encapsulates UIKit

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/cocoa-touch.html

Edit: to eliminate your other thoughts, iOS is the operating system for the phone, and Objective-C is the language.  What you're looking for is describing the frameworks you are using for your project-- i.e Cocoa Touch works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks MattyAyOh. I would use _Cocoa Touch_. Upvoted & Accepted !

Comment: No problem ^^  For future reference, SO is generally just used for technical questions-- so I think that's why you were down-voted so much.

Answer (score 2):

The front end of a project is the visual stuff, layout and design, animations, and interactive parts of the app. The backend is all the stuff the user doesn't know about, and doesn't care about, such as your data structure, data manipulation, web access, or any api you are using or connecting to. This is a simplified list of what constitutes the front and backend. Hopefully this clears this up for you.

Answer (score 2):

Front-end is part of the app that user can see and interact with.
Back-end is part of the app on server, database, web services...
For example, NSURLRequest is a class that would be used on front-end, using for call web services to interact with back-end.